# the future effects of Covid 19 pandemics on GINI (income inequality)

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, labor-economics, national-income

I would like to analyze the future effect of Covid 19 pandemics on the Gini index (income inequality).

Which dependent variables should I use in order to see the effect of the pandemics?

For example, I think that  I should use oil prices in order to include time fixed effects. But, which variables I should include? (Note that the variables should be accessible publicly, for example, from world bank data... etc.)

What are your opinions? Thank you.

Comment: Do you really mean the effect of the pandemic itself, or how governments measures affected economic outcomes?

Comment: Yes, both may be helpful and useful. What is your opinion for this effect? @BrsG

Comment: Also, I assume you are really looking for *independent* variables, to which you then want to link the *dependent* variable which is the Gini index?